# Facebook PHP SDK v4 - Getting back only page's scheduled posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, posts

I'm desperately trying to send a get request to /{page-id}/feed with params:

```
$result = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$fb_page_id.'/feed', array(
    'access_token' => $page_access_token['access_token'],
    'is_published' => 0,
    'since' => time()
)))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

But it won't return my already future scheduled posts.

Anyone have any ideas?

I've already tried FQL but I get a deprecated error (since v2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `promotable_posts` is the endpoint to get future scheduled posts too, check out the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

I did not test it, but scheduled posts are only mentioned for that endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Let's hope they don't deprecate this one too :/